# Bold italics is hard to distinguish from italics

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

The aim of any special mathematical notation for a particular class of objects is to allow the reader immediately recognise objects of this class in expressions.

For instance, the good old arrow notation for vectors works pretty well in that respect and when you see an expression like

[image]

you know that x is a vector variable, while t is a scalar one.

MWE to reproduce the result above

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{[Asana-Math]}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \Psi(\vec{x}, t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Now let's try to typeset vectors in bold italics in accordance with ISO regulations (see P.S.). The only thing we need to add in the previous example is redefinition on the \vec macro

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

And here is the result

[image]

The problem is that it is so hard to say is x bold or not and as a consequence of that I doubt a reader can understand that x is a vector variable, while t is a scalar one.

Yes, it depends on the choice of the math font. Asana Math is really bad, but it looks much better with, for example, Cambria Math

[image]

But Cambria Math is not free (as free beer) and has its own problems (no upright partial derivatives, huge summation and product symbols), so I would like to use Asana Math and if possible make bold italics "bolder".

Is it possible?

P.S. Can anyone actually confirm that ISO 80000-2:2009 requires typeset vectors in bold italics? This claim is basically everywhere but the referred document cost CHF 140,00 which is to expensive for me. I found the related Russian technical standard (ГОСТ Р 54521-2011) which is available for free and which has been developed to be compatible with ISO 80000-2:2009. And according to this standard [one can use good-old arrow](http://protect.gost.ru/v.aspx?control=8&baseC=-1&page=0&month=-1&year=-1&search=&RegNum=1&DocOnPageCount=15&id=171082&pageK=08329299-9B3E-4160-BF13-4C0F596A2484) instead of bold italics for vectors.

Comment: Eaxtly what are you using it for since you want to comply to ISO standards? Most mathematicians do not really care and often journals do not either.

Comment: In a sense, I'm just curious is it possible to follow ISO standard in principle right now with XeTeX? And the biggest problem so far is that bold italics for most fonts is very hard to distinguish from italics, which I obviously don't like.

Comment: You should of course compare bold and non-bold versions of the same character, otherwise the comparison is invalid. In the end it will depend on the given font. I have no idea if xelatex lets you make anything *bolder*

Comment: I like the "good old arrow" - it survives photocopying etc better, and is a well-understood convention.

Comment: @daleif the reader should be able to immediately get some information from mathematical notation about entities used in expression. The point is that bold italics in many fonts is not bold enough to be clearly identified as bold and I was looking for some sort of making bold symbols thicker. If there is no way to do that I would rather typeset vectors in bold upright which is de facto standard.

Comment: @Floris arrow also has some disadvantages. Sometimes you would like to reserve space on top of the symbol for something else. For example, I put circumflexes on top of linear operators and if some operator is vector one then it is resulted in hat on top of arrow on top of some symbol which doesn't look good.

Comment: @daleif I rewrite the question. I hope now it is clear why comparing bold and non-bold versions of the same character doesn't make any sense in the context of our discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a comparison of different math fonts:

[image]

The problem with the Palatino-like fonts (Asana and TG Pagella) is that only one of the **x** lines is thicker. The **r** looks bold even compared to the *t*. The Times-like fonts (TG Termes and XITS) have a thicker appearance, so if font switching is an option for you, you may want to try one of them.

If you want to use Asana I'd go with TeX style and use bold upright math, many books and journals use this style, so just because there is one written standard it does not mean that there aren't unwritten standards which many people follow.

[image]

Finally if you are considering to use an arrow to indicate a vector, I would use TG Pagella instead of Asana, because it has in my opinion a more appealing arrow.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\setmathfont{#1}$\Psi(\mathbf{x}, x, \mathbf{r}, r, %
                                        \mathbf{k}, t)$& #1\\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\test{Asana Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\test{XITS Math}
%\test{Tex Gyre Bonum Math}
\test{Cambria Math}
\test{Latin Modern Math}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that is true, and I consider this feature of Asana Math to be a bug. But I like Palatino-like fonts, so I'm not willing to switch.

Answer (score 2):

So far the only workaround I found is to use fake bold for bold italics

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{[Asana-Math]}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit,FakeBold=2.0]{[Asana-Math]}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \Psi(\vec{x}, t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result

[image]